# Colored math expression metapost

Tags: metapost

Is there a way in metapost to print a single label (in math notation) like this one

```
label(btex \Large{$3$} etex,(2,-1));
```

using some specific color like red or blue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does adding `withcolor red` before the semicolon work?

Comment: Perfectly. It was sooo simple, my fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple, but not without a couple of possible things to keep in mind.

`label` is defined in `plain.mp` to draw a <picture> variable in the right place.  If you pass a plain string it is automatically turned into a <picture> with `infont`.  If you pass a `btex ... etex` string it will have been turned into a <picture> before it gets passed to `label`.

So if you do `label(btex $3$ etex, (2,1));` this is essentially the same as

```
picture P;
P = btex $3$ etex;
draw P shifted (2,1);
```

And therefore if you do `label(btex $3$ etex, (2,1)) withcolor red;` this expands to

```
picture P;
P = btex $3$ etex;
draw P shifted (2,1) withcolor red;
```

And your label appears in red.  In plain MP, whatever is in the picture `P` will be drawn in red, only.  So you might like to consider this program:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
verbatimtex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
etex

beginfig(1);

picture T[]; 
T1 = btex $e=mc^2$ etex;
T2 = btex $\mathcolor{red}{e} = \mathcolor{blue}{mc}^2$ etex;
T3 = image(
    fill fullcircle scaled 22 -- reverse fullcircle scaled 14 -- cycle withcolor blue;
    fill unitsquare shifted -(1/2, 1/2) xscaled 36 yscaled 4 withcolor red;
) shifted 18 right;

for i = 1, 2, 3:
    draw T[i] shifted (0, -64i);
    draw T[i] shifted (60, -64i + 12) withcolor 1/2 red;
    draw T[i] shifted (60, -64i - 12) withcolor 1/2 green;
endfor

endfig;
end.
```

If you compile this with `mpost -tex=latex` you should get an EPS file that looks like this:

[image]

Notice that the three images get drawn "monochrome" when you add `withcolor` after the `draw` command.  Even if they are multicoloured originally.

### Extra note for `luamplib` users

There appears to be a quirk -- or perhaps a bug -- with the current TeXLive version of `luamplib`.  If you change the header of the program above, so that it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

beginfig(1);

picture T[]; 

T1 = btex $e=mc^2$ etex;
T2 = btex $\mathcolor{red}{e} = \mathcolor{blue}{mc}^2$ etex;
T3 = image(
    fill fullcircle scaled 22 -- reverse fullcircle scaled 14 -- cycle withcolor blue;
    fill unitsquare shifted -(1/2, 1/2) xscaled 36 yscaled 4 withcolor red;
) shifted 18 right;

for i = 1, 2, 3:
    draw T[i] shifted (0, -64i);
    draw T[i] shifted (60, -64i + 12) withcolor 1/2 red;
    draw T[i] shifted (60, -64i - 12) withcolor 1/2 green;
endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

and recompile with `lualatex` you will get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

For some reason, `withcolor` is being ignored if the <picture> contains coloured text.   Possibly this is a quirk of my own set up!